# My method don't reverse array of characters

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I have a code like this:

```
char* insert(int b, char a[],char c){

    //b - index of array a, c - character

    cin >> c;
    a[b] = c;
    b++;

    if(c == '.'){
        for(int i = b-1;i==0;i--)
        cout << a[i];
        return a;
    } 
    else if(c != '.') return insert(b, a,c); 

}

int main(){
    char znak = 0;
    char name[100];
    int licznik = 0;
    cout << insert(licznik, name, znak) << endl;
}
```

Method `insert(int b, char a[],char c)` should reverse my array if I imput a period. It only print this array but don't reverse it.

Comment: I don't see any data in `name`. Also, your insert function should take a parameter indicating the size of the string, otherwise you risk a buffer overflow.

Comment: `for(int i = b-1;i==0;i--)` is wrong. Try `for(int i = b-1;i>0;i--)` instead.

Comment: Even if I add data in name it doesn't change anything.

Comment: yeah, check the actual functioning of a for loop. basically the first expression is evaluated before the loop starts, the second needs to be true before every iteration, and the third is evaluated after every iteration. Not sure if it is after the last iteration...

Comment: @Adam it works, but partialy. If I imput "asdf." this will print "fdsasdf.". Don't know how can I break the loop in the last character.

Comment: You pass in the parameter `c` but then immediately overwrite it with `cin >>c`, so there's really no point in passing it.  What `insert` really does is read the next character from the stream and append it to array `a`.

Comment: this is c++, use `std::string`

Comment: Is there are reason you are using recursion?  You could do an in-string swap of the characters.

Answer (score 1):

A for loop in C++ is like a while loop with an an initialize stmt, an iterator and a condition, so this

```
for (int i=b-1; i==0; i--) {
    . . .
}
```

is equivalent to

```
int i=b-1;
while (i==0) {
    . . .;
    i--
}
```

In this form, you see that the only time that the body of the loop is executed is when i is 0, and then it only executes once.  What you probably meant is

```
for (int i=b-1; i>0; i--)
```

but also note that since you return the string and immediately print it, you'll get the forward version concatenated to the backward version.  In addition, since you record the '.' before checking for it, it will be part of the string.  Finally, since you don't properly terminate the string (with a null), when you print it out at the end you may get random garbage at the end of it.  Thus, if you run the program and enter "abcd." as input, you might get something like this as output:

```
.dcbabcd.0??^?
```

Comment: Its OK, I made some changes in my code and now everything works with flying colors! Thank you everyone.